# COM Interop registration

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a .NET assembly which I am exposing to [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model). The assembly has two public interfaces and one public class. When I build the assembly I get this warning:

> (assemblyName.dll) does not contain any types that can be registered for COM Interop.

My assembly information includes the following line.

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

Most people having this problem on the web, that I have found, fixed it with the above line in their assembly information. This has not helped for me.

I also tried adding `[ComVisible(true)]` to the class and interface definitions, and it also did not help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ComVisible classes generally need to have a public default constructor.  Its members should typically also reference only ComVisible types.

You don't need to specify ComVisible(true) on the class if you have specified it at the assembly level.

However, the usual way to generate an assembly with ComVisible classes is:

- Specify ComVisible(false) at assembly-level.  Thus only classes that are explicitly marked with ComVisible(true) are exposed to COM.
- Define an explicit ComVisible interface :

e.g.

```
[
ComVisible(true),
GuidAttribute("..."),
Description("...")
]
public interface IMyComVisibleType
{
        // members...
     }
```

- Your ComVisible class should specify ClassInterfaceType.None, and should implement the ComVisible interface:

e.g.

```
     [
     ComVisible(true),
     GuidAttribute("..."),
     ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
     ]
     public sealed class MyComVisibleType : IMyComVisibleType
     {
        // implementation ...
     }
```

Note that the Guid and Description attributes are not required, but useful to give you more control of the COM generation.

If the above doesn't help, try posting some sample code and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: Forgetting to add a default constructor happens to me sometimes so +1 to mention it.

Comment: Adding a public default constructor did the trick however, the class in question is only ever constructed from the .net code. This was the reason no public default constructor was provided. I assume that this warning would also appear for an assembly only containing interfaces.

Comment: Yes, you'll get the same warning for an assembly with only interfaces.  I guess it's similar to the way a VB6 ActiveX DLL must contain at least one publicly creatable class.  But it seems unnecessarily restrictive in the .NET world, as you could have a class constructed by managed code and passed to a COM component e.g. as a method argument.

Comment: I had issues with UUID format for GuidAttribute and this link helped me to resolve it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0e48ss8.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the default constructor problem. What fooled me was that the type library file will contain the class GUID reference even though that class is not being registered.  A quick way to see what will be registered is to create a registry file ('assembly.reg') like this:

```
regasm assembly.dll /regfile:assembly.reg /codebase
```

There's a good discussion of exposing interfaces in [COM Interop: Base class properties not exposed to COM](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7313191a-10db-4a16-9cdd-de9fb80b378a/). Some example code is here: [Exposing .NET Components to COM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few other things to true

- Make sure the types you want to register are marked as public
- Add the `ComVisible(true)` attribute to the type directly in addition to the assembly
- Add the `Guid` attribute

Not sure if the last 2 are strictly necessary but I would try them out.

Comment: The GUID is generated at build time based on a has of the fully-qualified class name and the identity of the assembly containing the class. ie not necessary to do this yourself.

Comment: Tried the ComVisable(true) on the types + double checked that the types are public. Still no luck.

Comment: What about adding a GUID attribute to each exposed class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a strong-named assembly. Do you sign your assembly with a key file?

Further, also try specifying :
    [Guid("{newly generated GUID}")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]

Comment: no I don't but it doesn't need to be strong named I have other .net assemblies which work for com interop and are not stong named.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it must also have a default parameter-less public constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a project where I checked the "Register For COM interop" option for my C# project. There is an easy solution:

While in the Solution Explorer, go to the Properties folder.  Open the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.  Scroll down to the line that says:
`[assembly: ComVisible(false)]`

Change this to:
`[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`

This will remove the warning messages, and allows the `.tlb` file to be created, which then enables the .NET code for COM visibility.
 If you don't want the entire assembly to be COM-visible then follow one of the other tips above.